# where to implement network operation in android service or in background thread?

Tags: android, networking, service, local-storage, background-process

In my android application there is long network operation todo.
1.Is that good practice to move all network operation to service ?
2.IF I need to load/store data to file system, where to do this in service ? main thread ?
  background thread under service ? or background thread under main thread ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1. For networkoperations have a look at the [Volley library](http://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html).
2. To store data to the file system use a [Content Provider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html).

Never do blocking operations (like large database operations) in the Main Thread (causes "Application Not Responding" - ANR messages).